# Using CQL to walk partition keys of a Cassandra table

Tags: sql, cassandra, partitioning, cql, cql3

Using CQL3, how does one enumerate all the partition keys of a table in Cassandra? In particular there are complications with returning distinct keys, and paginating the results.

Comment: Check [this blogpost](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24) by Richard, it goes into great detail why it's hard to count keys in a distributed system.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov: I'm aware of the difficulties. However I'm just after the keys, I don't care for count or consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little pre-knowledge about the possible values of your keys, I think this could be done using with the help of the token function. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11889327/2459609). Is that what you are looking for?

Also, native pagination seems to be [an upcoming feature for 2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4415). It's [in the latest beta](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0).

Until 2.0 arrives, you can see this [work-around for pagination](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive) on the datastax blog (go the "CQL3 pagination" section). This is, in principle, much the same as the link I posted above but goes into great detail how to implement pagination taking column keys into account etc.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't allow pagination for this purpose.

Comment: I updated my answer to link a more detailed example how to use the token & limit queries I linked to previously.

Comment: About paging using `TOKEN` function [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) in DataStax Docs page.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as in the following example.  Create a test table:

```
> create table partition_keys_test (p_key text PRIMARY KEY, rest text);
```

and insert some rows e.g.:

```
> insert into partition_keys_test (p_key, rest) VALUES ('1', 'blah');
```

I did this for p_key '1', '2', ..., '9'.

Then page through the partition keys.  Start with:

```
> select p_key from partition_keys_test limit 2;
 p_key
 -------
     6
     7
```

for page size 2.  Then, take your last p_key result and use it in the next query:

```
> select p_key from partition_keys_test where token(p_key) > token('7') limit 2;
 p_key
 -------
    9
    4
```

and so on, until you receive less than your page size results.

Note that you should expect this to read through your entire data set.  For very wide rows it may not, but will still be very I/O heavy.

Also, if rows are created or removed and have tokens higher than you've got to so far, they will appear in subsequent queries.  So if you are running the above paging queries while you are creating or removing rows, the partition keys may or may not be returned, depending on timing.

Comment: What can you use as a starting token, without having to have 2 different query strings? How will your query handle multiple rows for each primary key? For instance imagine there were 2 fields in the primary key, p_key being the partition key. Now there can be multiple rows with the same p_key.

Comment: token('') returns minimum, so you can replace the first query with `select p_key from partition_keys_test where token(p_key) > token('') limit 2;`. If you have a composite primary key then you will get duplicates. I don't think there's any way to filter out duplicates server side.

Comment: Correct, but this doesn't work in the general case of compound PK; see my answer below.

Comment: Apart from the annoyance of filtering out duplicates manually, why won't this method obtain all partition keys?

Answer (score 4):

The bad news is that for now (August 2013) you have to select the entire primary key, not just the partition key, to paginate through them.  With a compound PK, this may involve a lot of duplicate partition keys.

The good news is that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4536 is open to allow `SELECT DISTINCT` for the special case of partition keys in 2.0.1, since it's possible to retrieve the unique partition keys efficiently under the hood; CQL just doesn't have a good way to express that until then.